# How to send a get request to a jsonresult with a string parameter using JavaScript Fetch?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, fetch-api, jsonresult

Im trying to fetch an **api** from the server. im using mvc **jsonresult** to create the api. the jsonresult takes string id as a parameter. So how can i pass the id from the client to the server using fetch?

I tried to send the id just like an int or any numeric value but it didn't work! i also tried to pass it as a query string but it also didn't work!

This is how i first tried to pass the id:

```
fetch(`/controller/jsonresult/${id}`)
```

I also tried to fetch it as a query string

```
fetch(`/controller/jsonresult/get?id=${id}`)
```

I expected that the string will reach the **jsonresult** so i can get the information according to the id but it always receives null

Comment: Did you try [JavaScriptSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) or [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)? Did you try `console.log` it to see if you get a value?

Comment: @Tico i tried debugging with postman and the id was null

Comment: Yeah, but I meant server side (C#, I'm guessing).

Comment: @Tico i really dont know how but it worked! using the first way! Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a while ago but forgot to post here sorry!

I was using the [Authorize] data annotation in my controller and thats why i wasn't able to get the jsonresult from my controller!

it worked just fine,

```
fetch(`/controller/jsonresult/${id}`)
```